# Workflow send link in email to item created by the workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am creating a workflow with the following steps.

1. Associate fills out form on a SharePoint team site
2. Admin receives email with form details
3. Admin approves volunteer hours
4. Associate receives approval via email

This involves two lists.
Associate Form and Approval Status.

The workflow is set off when an associate creates an item on Associate Form. The workflows first step is to create an item in Approval Status with the Associate name and other information.

The second step is sending out the email to admins with the data filled out in Associate Form and a link to go to the edit page of the item just created in Approval Status by step 1.

The thing that has me stuck is how can I get a link to edit the item created in Approval Status in the email sent out after the first step?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Site Column called "Approval Status URL" and add it to the Associate Form library or list.
Have your Workflow put the link to the Approval Status edit Form in the Approval Status URL column. You may need to have a hard coded URL with a lookup to the list Name field. When you open the Approval Status list item in edit mode,copy and past the URL into Notepad. You will notice the URL will stay the same except for the item name that changes. Use that as your hard coded URL with the lookup. Then you can reference the newly created Approval Status URL with the link you need know your WF.